Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'color' property of scatter.line Received value: 'rgba(166, 206, 227, np.float64(1.0))'
I am using this set of imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from chart_studio import plotly
# import plotly.plotly as pl
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as of
import cufflinks as cf
import datetime as dt
%matplotlib inline

of.init_notebook_mode(connected = True)
cf.go_offline()

And when i try to run this code
df.iplot(kind='scatter',xTitle='Projects',
         yTitle='Donations',title='Projects vs Donations',
         symbol='x',colorscale='paired',mode='markers')

**It throws error **
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[94], line 1
----> 1 df.iplot(kind='scatter',xTitle='Projects',
      2          yTitle='Donations',title='Projects vs Donations',
      3          symbol='x',colorscale='paired',mode='markers')

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\cufflinks\plotlytools.py:839, in _iplot(self, kind, data, layout, filename, sharing, title, xTitle, yTitle, zTitle, theme, colors, colorscale, fill, width, dash, mode, interpolation, symbol, size, barmode, sortbars, bargap, bargroupgap, bins, histnorm, histfunc, orientation, boxpoints, annotations, keys, bestfit, bestfit_colors, mean, mean_colors, categories, x, y, z, text, gridcolor, zerolinecolor, margin, labels, values, secondary_y, secondary_y_title, subplots, shape, error_x, error_y, error_type, locations, lon, lat, asFrame, asDates, asFigure, asImage, dimensions, asPlot, asUrl, online, **kwargs)
    837     if not isinstance(text,list):
    838         text=self[text].values
--> 839 data=df.to_iplot(colors=colors,colorscale=colorscale,kind=kind,interpolation=interpolation,fill=fill,width=width,dash=dash,sortbars=sortbars,keys=keys,
    840         bestfit=bestfit,bestfit_colors=bestfit_colors,mean=mean,mean_colors=mean_colors,asDates=asDates,mode=mode,symbol=symbol,size=size,
    841         text=text,**kwargs)     
    842 trace_kw=check_kwargs(kwargs,TRACE_KWARGS)
    843 for trace in data:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\cufflinks\plotlytools.py:161, in _to_iplot(self, colors, colorscale, kind, mode, interpolation, symbol, size, fill, width, dash, sortbars, keys, bestfit, bestfit_colors, opacity, mean, mean_colors, asDates, asTimestamp, text, **kwargs)
    159     lines_plotly=[Bar(lines[key]).to_plotly_json() for key in keys]
    160 else:
--> 161     lines_plotly=[Scatter(lines[key]).to_plotly_json() for key in keys]
    162 for trace in lines_plotly:
    163     if isinstance(trace['name'],pd.Timestamp):

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\_scatter.py:3530, in Scatter.__init__(self, arg, alignmentgroup, cliponaxis, connectgaps, customdata, customdatasrc, dx, dy, error_x, error_y, fill, fillcolor, fillgradient, fillpattern, groupnorm, hoverinfo, hoverinfosrc, hoverlabel, hoveron, hovertemplate, hovertemplatesrc, hovertext, hovertextsrc, ids, idssrc, legend, legendgroup, legendgrouptitle, legendrank, legendwidth, line, marker, meta, metasrc, mode, name, offsetgroup, opacity, orientation, selected, selectedpoints, showlegend, stackgaps, stackgroup, stream, text, textfont, textposition, textpositionsrc, textsrc, texttemplate, texttemplatesrc, uid, uirevision, unselected, visible, x, x0, xaxis, xcalendar, xhoverformat, xperiod, xperiod0, xperiodalignment, xsrc, y, y0, yaxis, ycalendar, yhoverformat, yperiod, yperiod0, yperiodalignment, ysrc, zorder, **kwargs)
   3528 _v = line if line is not None else _v
   3529 if _v is not None:
-> 3530     self["line"] = _v
   3531 _v = arg.pop("marker", None)
   3532 _v = marker if marker is not None else _v

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py:4860, in BasePlotlyType.__setitem__(self, prop, value)
   4858 # ### Handle compound property ###
   4859 if isinstance(validator, CompoundValidator):
-> 4860     self._set_compound_prop(prop, value)
   4862 # ### Handle compound array property ###
   4863 elif isinstance(validator, (CompoundArrayValidator, BaseDataValidator)):

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py:5271, in BasePlotlyType._set_compound_prop(self, prop, val)
   5268 # Import value
   5269 # ------------
   5270 validator = self._get_validator(prop)
-> 5271 val = validator.validate_coerce(val, skip_invalid=self._skip_invalid)
   5273 # Save deep copies of current and new states
   5274 # ------------------------------------------
   5275 curr_val = self._compound_props.get(prop, None)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py:2512, in CompoundValidator.validate_coerce(self, v, skip_invalid, _validate)
   2509     v = self.data_class()
   2511 elif isinstance(v, dict):
-> 2512     v = self.data_class(v, skip_invalid=skip_invalid, _validate=_validate)
   2514 elif isinstance(v, self.data_class):
   2515     # Copy object
   2516     v = self.data_class(v)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\scatter\_line.py:374, in Line.__init__(self, arg, backoff, backoffsrc, color, dash, shape, simplify, smoothing, width, **kwargs)
    372 _v = color if color is not None else _v
    373 if _v is not None:
--> 374     self["color"] = _v
    375 _v = arg.pop("dash", None)
    376 _v = dash if dash is not None else _v

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py:4868, in BasePlotlyType.__setitem__(self, prop, value)
   4864         self._set_array_prop(prop, value)
   4866     # ### Handle simple property ###
   4867     else:
-> 4868         self._set_prop(prop, value)
   4869 else:
   4870     # Make sure properties dict is initialized
   4871     self._init_props()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py:5212, in BasePlotlyType._set_prop(self, prop, val)
   5210         return
   5211     else:
-> 5212         raise err
   5214 # val is None
   5215 # -----------
   5216 if val is None:
   5217     # Check if we should send null update

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py:5207, in BasePlotlyType._set_prop(self, prop, val)
   5204 validator = self._get_validator(prop)
   5206 try:
-> 5207     val = validator.validate_coerce(val)
   5208 except ValueError as err:
   5209     if self._skip_invalid:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py:1411, in ColorValidator.validate_coerce(self, v, should_raise)
   1409     validated_v = self.vc_scalar(v)
   1410     if validated_v is None and should_raise:
-> 1411         self.raise_invalid_val(v)
   1413     v = validated_v
   1415 return v

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py:296, in BaseValidator.raise_invalid_val(self, v, inds)
    293             for i in inds:
    294                 name += "[" + str(i) + "]"
--> 296         raise ValueError(
    297             """
    298     Invalid value of type {typ} received for the '{name}' property of {pname}
    299         Received value: {v}
    300 
    301 {valid_clr_desc}""".format(
    302                 name=name,
    303                 pname=self.parent_name,
    304                 typ=type_str(v),
    305                 v=repr(v),
    306                 valid_clr_desc=self.description(),
    307             )
    308         )

ValueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'color' property of scatter.line
        Received value: 'rgba(166, 206, 227, np.float64(1.0))'

    The 'color' property is a color and may be specified as:
      - A hex string (e.g. '#ff0000')
      - An rgb/rgba string (e.g. 'rgb(255,0,0)')
      - An hsl/hsla string (e.g. 'hsl(0,100%,50%)')
      - An hsv/hsva string (e.g. 'hsv(0,100%,100%)')
      - A named CSS color:
            aliceblue, antiquewhite, aqua, aquamarine, azure,
            beige, bisque, black, blanchedalmond, blue,
            blueviolet, brown, burlywood, cadetblue,
            chartreuse, chocolate, coral, cornflowerblue,
            cornsilk, crimson, cyan, darkblue, darkcyan,
            darkgoldenrod, darkgray, darkgrey, darkgreen,
            darkkhaki, darkmagenta, darkolivegreen, darkorange,
            darkorchid, darkred, darksalmon, darkseagreen,
            darkslateblue, darkslategray, darkslategrey,
            darkturquoise, darkviolet, deeppink, deepskyblue,
            dimgray, dimgrey, dodgerblue, firebrick,
            floralwhite, forestgreen, fuchsia, gainsboro,
            ghostwhite, gold, goldenrod, gray, grey, green,
            greenyellow, honeydew, hotpink, indianred, indigo,
            ivory, khaki, lavender, lavenderblush, lawngreen,
            lemonchiffon, lightblue, lightcoral, lightcyan,
            lightgoldenrodyellow, lightgray, lightgrey,
            lightgreen, lightpink, lightsalmon, lightseagreen,
            lightskyblue, lightslategray, lightslategrey,
            lightsteelblue, lightyellow, lime, limegreen,
            linen, magenta, maroon, mediumaquamarine,
            mediumblue, mediumorchid, mediumpurple,
            mediumseagreen, mediumslateblue, mediumspringgreen,
            mediumturquoise, mediumvioletred, midnightblue,
            mintcream, mistyrose, moccasin, navajowhite, navy,
            oldlace, olive, olivedrab, orange, orangered,
            orchid, palegoldenrod, palegreen, paleturquoise,
            palevioletred, papayawhip, peachpuff, peru, pink,
            plum, powderblue, purple, red, rosybrown,
            royalblue, rebeccapurple, saddlebrown, salmon,
            sandybrown, seagreen, seashell, sienna, silver,
            skyblue, slateblue, slategray, slategrey, snow,
            springgreen, steelblue, tan, teal, thistle, tomato,
            turquoise, violet, wheat, white, whitesmoke,
            yellow, yellowgreen

This is what I get (Output Image)
I tried to change the versions of the plotly module to older one.
Also with this set of code  the required graph can be obtained but i want to use the intractive plot (iplot) for better and detailed graphs.
df.plot.scatter(xlabel='Projects', ylabel='Donations', title='Projects vs Donations' , x='Projects', y='Donations')
plt.show()

